# Set animation to view change - Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I have this code:

```
backFromPlayers: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    var Dashboard = Ext.create('HTMS.view.Dashboard');
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Dashboard);
},
```

As You can see, first I create view called "Dashboard", then I set it as active.
Problem is that, I don't understand how to set up animation to `setActiveItem` method.
I can set animation to that view as default, for example:

```
Ext.define('HTMS.view.Dashboard', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
alias: 'widget.dashboard',

requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.Button'
],

config: {
    style: 'background: #fff;',
    scrollable: true,
    showAnimation: {
        type: 'slide',
        direction: 'left'
    },
// Rest code
```

But I need to change direction depending on place where I call "Dashboard" view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [setAnimation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.0/#!/api/Ext.layout.Default-method-setAnimation) to modify the direction, try

```
backFromPlayers: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    var Dashboard = Ext.create('HTMS.view.Dashboard');
    var direction = 'right'; //[or] left;
    Ext.Viewport.getLayout().setAnimation({type: 'slide', direction: direction});
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Dashboard);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you know how to set this animation if in Ajax request?